# Looking for a Website Theme Similar to This

Tags: javascript, cms, wordpress

I’m looking to make a website like http://www.blitzagency.com/ or at least similar to it. I really like how when you scroll down, the page sections rotate like cubes. What CMS/Theme or JavaScript plugin was used on that site? Is a WordPress theme available to make my website like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had looked at the source for the page you would have found that the page authors had already answered your questions for you in an nice comment at the top:

```
You're likely looking at this because you are curious how we did what we did..
well we are more than happy to point you in the right direction :)
BLITZ wrote a custom framework built on top of Famo.us and Marionette.js
You can find more information about it here:
https://github.com/blitzagency/rich
(it's open source)
```

So yes it is available but not as a WordPress theme - you will have to do some hand coding. *I wish that there was a way of +1ing the webs site authors for their candor and helpfulness as well as the excellent site look.*